# SVN commit error, non-existing file not under version control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

Trying to SVN commit, but I get this error:

`svn: E200009: 'C:\dev\train-data\version'' is not under version control`

Problem is the file/directory `version'` doesn't exist. Neither does the file/directory `version`.

Even if I try to SVN commit in trunk, I get the same error:

`svn: E200009: 'C:\dev\train-data\trunk\version'' is not under version control`

I have tried deleting the .svn directory in `C:\dev\train-data\`, but that didn't fix the problem.

Client is Tortoise SVN command line on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Turns out that the `'` in the SVN command was the cause of the problem.

So this one doesn't work:
`svn ci -m 'Commit message'`

This one does work:
`svn ci -m "Commit message"`